# When should I split my code into multiple packages, and what's a good way to split it?

Tags: ros, package, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(Mention the advantages of message definition packages.)

Please help in writing up a ROS best practice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11835/when-should-i-split-my-code-into-multiple-packages,-and-what%27s-a-good-way-to-split-it?/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your ROS packages should belong to one or more repositories. Each repository contains one or more [packages](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Packages), the build dependency units.

When creating a new package, choose the name carefully:

- Package names are global to the entire ROS ecosystem.
- They are messy to change later.
- Try to pick names that will make sense to others who may wish to use your code.
- Package names should start with a letter, and contain only letters, numbers and '`_`' characters. Lower case is preferred. Feel free to [browse the current list](http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php) for inspiriation.

Each package can be built separately, so pay attention to dependencies. The package dependency graph *must* be acyclic, i.e. no package may depend on another that directly or indirectly depends on it.

- The overhead of a ROS package is not large. Define separate packages wherever they make sense.
- Avoid combining nodes that pull in mutually unneeded dependencies.
- To eliminate unnecessary build overhead, avoid combining nodes that are often used separately.
- If programs with similar dependencies are generally used together, consider combining them into a single package.
- If some nodes have common dependencies on shared code that you do not wish to export publicly, they can be combined internally within a single package.
- If the shared code should be exported, consider making it a separate package that the others depend on. (This is reasonable, but not required. A single package can export libraries and headers as well as nodes.)
- **Consider combining message definitions in one or more separate packages.** That usually simplifies the dependencies among packages, with nodes depending on the messages, and not so much on each other.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-26**:
thanks joq for supplying the first answer :)